# different content for the same session?

Tags: php, session-cookies

I have 2 php pages in the same domain. One is in the root, other one is 3 folder below.
A also have the following code in both files:

```
[...]
session_start();
var_dump(array('id' => session_id(), 'name' => session_name(), 'content' => $_SESSION));
die();
[...]
```

`id` is the same, `name` is the same, `content` differs...

If I execute `session_regenerate_id()` in any of them, both pages will have the new session id, but `content` still differs.
Cleaning up browser cache and wiping out all existing cookies won't help.

what have I missed?

Comment: All kinds of settings can differ per-dir. If you add the output of `ini_get_all('session')` to your dump, what differences do you see? (Usual suspects: other save_handler or save_path).

Comment: Judging only by the code you provided, that can't be, there must be an error somewhere else.

Comment: Can you paste the cookie headers (using dev console or firebug) please.

Comment: @Wrikken: the point is yours, 'session.save_path' is different. So there are two files with same name but different content. Thanx for the help!!!

Comment: OK, I'll promote it to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All kinds of session settings can differ per-dir. Note that these can be set in php configuration, host configuration, per-dir configuration (in apache: .htaccess), but *also in code*.

To determine what differs, inspecting the output of `ini_get_all('session')` at the point in the code you use the session probably shows the difference in settings.

With the described symptoms (session id is the same for the different dirs, but the stored content varies), the most likely reasons are that either `save_handler` is different (another mechanism is used to store the session, e.g. files vs. memcached), or `save_path` is different (another location is used for storing the sessions). In this case it was the `save_path` according to the comments.

Note that if the session-id is *different* in the 2 directories, the most likely cause is an incorrect `cookie_path` setting, if it differs between subdomains, look at the `cookie_domain` setting.